# Returning new Error appears in then not catch function?

Tags: javascript

I have a login function which returns an Error when a login attempt fails:

```
export const login = async () => {
  try {
    // Code to get res

    if (res.status === 200) {
      document.cookie = `userToken=${data.token}`;
    } else if (res.status === 400) {
      return new Error("Oh noo!!!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert('err!! ', err);
  }
};
```

The login form calls it with this:

```
submit = async event => {
    login()
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res ', res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err ', err);
      });
  };
```

When res.status is 400 and an Error is returned it appears in the `then` function not the `catch` function. How can I instead make it appear in the `catch` function? I assume this is best practice as the login attempt has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the interpreter sees an expresssion after `return`, that expression *will be returned* as soon as it's evaluated - even if it's an error, it won't go into the `catch` block. Declaring an error by itself won't cause a problem either - you need to actually *throw* it:

```
} else if (res.status === 400) {
  throw new Error("Oh noo!!!");
}
```

If you want the `submit` function to handle the error as well, then don't put the `try` / `catch` in `login`, because then the async function call will *resolve* rather than be *rejected* - instead, just let `login` throw, while `submit` handles the `catch`:

```
export const login = async () => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    document.cookie = `userToken=${data.token}`;
  } else if (res.status === 400) {
    throw new Error("Oh noo!!!");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `throw` the error instead of returning it, `throw ...` raises an exception in the current code block and causes it to exit, or to flow to next `catch` statement if raised in a `try` block.

```
export const login = async () => {
  try {
    // Code to get res

    if (res.status === 200) {
      document.cookie = `userToken=${data.token}`;
    } else if (res.status === 400) {
      throw Error("Oh noo!!!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert('err!! ', err);
  }
};
```